# Apple iPad Air - No screen rotation control

Tags: ios, ipad, screen

I'm running iOS 12.1 on an iPad Air.

Regardless of the switch setting (mute or rotatation) the side switch does not control screen rotation. There is no rotation control icon available to select under control centre. There is NO rotation control.

What do I need to do in order to control screen rotation on my iPad?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried turning it on and off in control centre. Access it by sliding up from the top-right on iPad:

[image: gif]

Rotation lock off:

[image: off]

Rotation lock on:

[image: on]

Answer (score 1):

There was no “Rotation” control icon in the control center. Reboot, and it “Automagically” appeared for the first time... EVER.!?? Forget the switch... this control will suffice. Thanks for trying to help!
  ~fss